# The tables in the .Rmd file are not displayed properly when exporting the file to HTML

Tags: r, r-markdown, rnotebook

I have a .Rmd file and I want to export it to a HTML file.
But the tables look wrong. In Rstudio the table looks good:

[image]

But when I export it to HTML (or PDF, Word, clicking on 'Knit'), then the table is not displayed properly:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for `kable`, which can output md table, and set the `results` option to `asis`.

````
```{r, results='asis'}
efficient <- mtcars[mtcars$mpg > 23,]
knitr::kable(efficient)
```
````